# Is my mySQL query as efficient as it could be?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL query which takes a long time to process. I am querying a large table of IP ranges which relate to country codes to discover the country of origin for each IP in the url_click table. (IP database from from hxxp://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/)

It works brilliantly, albeit slowly.

Is there a more efficient way to write this query?

Table and output JPG: http://tiny.cx/a4e00d

```
SELECT ip_addr AS IP, geo_ip.ctry, count(ip_addr) as count
FROM `admin_adfly`.`url_click`,admin_adfly.geo_ip
WHERE INET_ATON (ip_addr) 
BETWEEN geo_ip.ipfrom AND geo_ip.ipto 
AND url_id = 165 
GROUP BY ip_addr;
```

Comment: May I recommend http://codereview.stackexchange.com for this sort of thing?

Comment: I suspect filtering the results on `INET_ATON()` of a column would mean it'd have to scan the table applying `INET_ATON()` to everything with `url_id=165` - could  you pre-`INET_ATON()` your addresses somehow, as a column? Also, do you have an index on url_id? Also, what do you get if you ask MySQL to `EXPLAIN` the query?

Comment: thanks everyone. I tried Quassnoi's suggestion of creating an index but for some reason I couldn't create a b-tree storage type. I then tried Jonathan Leffler's suggestion and this did shave seconds off the query, but it did still take too long. I have decided to query the country related to the IP at the point of initial record entry rather than post query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of a function in the join between the two tables is going to be slower than a normal join, so you probably want to defer that particular operation as long as possible.  So, I'd summarize the data and then join it:

```
SELECT S.IP_Addr, G.Ctry AS Country, S.Count
  FROM (SELECT ip_addr, COUNT(ip_addr) AS Count
          FROM admin_adfly.url_click 
         WHERE url_id = 165 
         GROUP BY ip_addr) AS S
  JOIN admin_adfly.geo_ip AS G
    ON INET_ATON (ip_addr) BETWEEN geo_ip.ipfrom AND geo_ip.ipto;
```

If you can redesign the schema and are going to be doing a lot of this analysis, rework one of the two tables so that the join condition doesn't need to use INET_ATON().

Presumably, you have an index on the `url_id` column; that is the only one that will give you much benefit here.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses have a tree like structure and the ranges you have in your geo_ip table most probably respect that structure.

If your IP begins with 193.167, then you should have an index helping you filter the geo_ip table very quickly so that only the lines related to a subrange of 193.167 are manipulated.

I think that you should be able to dramatically improve the response time with this approach.

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

That `INET_ATON` worries me just a bit.  It'd make any index on the `ip_addr` column useless.  If you have a way of putting the info all in the same format, say by converting the data to a number before putting it in the DB, that might help.

Other than that, the standard advice about judicious use of indexes applies.  You might want indexes on `ipfrom` and `ipto`, and/or `url_id` columns.

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` does not optimize queries like this well.

You would need to convert your `ipfrom-ipto` ranges into `LineStrings`, thus allowing building an `R-Tree` index over them:

```
ALTER TABLE
        geo_ip
ADD     range LINESTRING;

UPDATE  geo_ip 
SET     range = LINESTRING(POINT(-1, ipfrom), POINT(1, ipfrom));

ALTER TABLE
        geo_ip
MODIFY  range LINESTRING NOT NULL;

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX
        sx_geoip_range
ON      geo_ip (range); 

SELECT  ip_addr AS IP, geo_ip.ctry, COUNT(*)
FROM    `admin_adfly`.`url_click`
JOIN    admin_adfly.geo_ip
ON      MBRContains
                (
                Point(0, INET_ATON (ip_addr)),
                range
                )
WHERE   url_id = 165 
GROUP BY
        ip_addr
```

`geo_ip` should be a `MyISAM` table.

See here for more details:

- [**Banning IPs**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/04/banning-ips/)